# Python's calcsize is being weird

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to deal with binary data in python and weird things happen.

```
from struct import *
print(calcsize('c')) #prints 1
print(calcsize('h')) #stands for short, prints 2
print(calcsize('ch')) #prints 4 O_O
```

How can this be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because individual values have to be aligned correctly, native to the system. In this case, the short needs to be aligned on an even byte. So when you do `ch`, the memory uses the bytes like this:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ c │   │   h   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

So there is one unoccupied byte left. You can fill that using another `char` without increasing the total size:

```
>>> calcsize('cch')
4
```

But if you put a `char` at the end, you are increasing the size again:

```
>>> calcsize('chc')
5
```

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ c │   │   h   │ c │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

Btw. you can also overwrite this alignment by adding a [control character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) to the beginning. For example, you can add a `=` at the beginning to turn off native alignment completely:

```
>>> calcsize('=ch')
3
```